# If number of points of discontinuity of the function $f(x)=\lfloor{2+10 \sin x\rfloor}$,in $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ is same as

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

If number of points of discontinuity of the function $f(x)=\lfloor{2+10 \sin x\rfloor}$,in $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ is same as number of points of non-differentiability of the function $g(x)=(x-1)(x-2)|(x-1)(x-2)....(x-2m)|,m\in N$ in $x \in (-\infty,\infty)$,then find the value of $m$

---

I drew the graph of $f(x)=\lfloor2+10 \sin x\rfloor$,in $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ and counted points of discontinuity are $9$ 
And i counted the number of points of non-differentiability of the function $g(x)=(x-1)(x-2)|(x-1)(x-2)....(x-2m)|$ are $2m-2$ because the function will be differentiable at $x=1,2$.
So $2m-2=9$
$m=5.5$ but the question says $m$ should be natural number.I dont know where i am wrong.
Please help me.Thanks.

Comment: I am not able to see anything wrong with your work....